# Remove the leftmost column from ranger file manager

Tags: ranger

There is a way I can remove the rightmost column:

```py
# Preview files on the rightmost column?
# And collapse (shrink) the last column if there is nothing to preview?
set preview_files false
set preview_directories false
set collapse_preview true
```

But how do I remove the leftmost column which shows the parent directory?

I know that I can use `set viewmode=multipane` to get single column. But in that case, when I use two tabs, I get two columns for two tabs, in the same screen. I want a screen per tab, but I want each screen to be composed of single column. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the column ratios to hide the left-most column:

```
set column_ratios 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557870/54670) you may also want to set the following option in order to remove the small gap on the right side where the collapsed preview pane is:

```
set padding_right false
```